# trouble in django staticfiles

Tags: django, static

I am having trouble serving my staticfiles. Using django 2.0

This is the settings file,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I ran collectstatic and then every static file was copied in the STATIC_ROOT folder.

The thing is the admin static files and rest framework are being served, but not the ones which I have added.

```
(env) luvpreet@nfs:~/myntracms/myntracms$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.BASE_DIR
'/home/luvpreet/myntracms/myntracms/myntracms'
```

See this,

```
luvpreet@nfs:~/myntracms/myntracms/static$ pwd
/home/luvpreet/myntracms/myntracms/static

luvpreet@nfs:~/myntracms/myntracms/static$ ls
admin  debug_toolbar  djcelery  images  js  rest_framework

luvpreet@nfs:~/myntracms/myntracms/static$
```

Admin static files work,

[image]

But my files are not being served,

[image]

Even if I paste my files in the admin folder, still they are not being served.

```
luvpreet@nfs:~/myntracms/myntracms/static/admin/js$ ls | grep home
home.png
```

But still,

[image]

Comment: Are you running in development mode (ie `python manage.py runserver`).  If yes, you'll need to include `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` in your `urls.py`

Comment: did you setup it with nginx or apache2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT) (where static files are collected to), but you haven't set [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) (where static files are collected *from*).

It looks as if you want

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR),'static')]
```

You should then change `STATIC_ROOT` to be a different directory (often outside of your Django project). You can also remove the directories that have been collected to `~/myntracms/myntracms/static/` (e.g. `admin` and `django-debug-toolbar`).